How to suppress longitudinal stress waves in a beam in FEA
When simulating a bending beam in FEA mimicking the textbook model and approach, unwanted stress waves appear. How to suppress longitudinal stress waves in a beam in FEA? To add friction/damping?

What type of elements are you using and which boundary conditions? Could you also add a picture with these unwanted waves?

General purpose 3d elements and free boundary conditions.  I lost the pictures but the wave is just a typical longitudinal wave

Is the simulation dynamic? In such case, wave could make sense. On the other hand, if it is static, you cannot use "free" boundary conditions, you need to restrain some displacements/rotations.

yes dynamical, but I hope to kill such waves

Without a picture, it is very difficult to guess what might have gone wrong. If you are still experiencing the issue, I am sure you can easily produce a new picture and post it here.
